# Automocking Web Api 2 controller

Tags: c#, autofixture, automoq

I am trying to auto mock ApiController class in my test cases. It worked perfectly when I was using WebApi1. I started to use WebApi2 on the new project and I am getting this exception thrown after I try to run my new tests:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: pCertContext is an invalid handle.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CAPI.CertSetCertificateContextProperty(SafeCertContextHandle pCertContext, UInt32 dwPropId, UInt32 dwFlags, SafeLocalAllocHandle safeLocalAllocHandle)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.set_Archived(Boolean value)
```

My test code:

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void approparte_status_code_is_returned(
    string privateKey,
    UsersController sut)
{
    var response = sut.GetUser(privateKey);
    var result = response;

    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
}
```

Test case does work if I create sut manually:

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void approparte_status_code_is_returned(
    string privateKey,
    [Frozen]Mock<IUserModel> stubModel)
{
    var sut = new UsersController(stubModel.Object);
    var response = sut.GetUser(privateKey);
    var result = response;

    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
}
```

It's seems that something goes wrong when trying to mock the ControllerContext.RequestContext.ClientCertificate I've tried to create a fixture without it (using AutoFixture .Without() method) but then even the old tests started to fail.

My AutoMoqDataAttribute:

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqDataAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture()
            .Customize(new WebApiCustomization()))
    {
    }
}
```

WebApi customization:

```
public class WebApiCustomization : CompositeCustomization
{
    public WebApiCustomization() 
        : base(
        new HttpRequestMessageCustomization(),
        new AutoMoqCustomization())
    {
    }
}
```

HttpRequestMessage customization:

```
public class HttpRequestMessageCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<HttpRequestMessage>(c => c
            .Without(x => x.Content)
            .Do(x =>
            {
                x.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = new HttpConfiguration();
            })
            );
    }
}
```

UsersController:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles user's account. 
/// </summary>
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/users/{privateKey:length(64)}")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUserModel _model;

    public UsersController(IUserModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="privateKey">The private key of the user.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// 200 (OK) with user data is returned when user is found.
    /// 404 (Not found) is returned when user is not found.
    /// </returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetUser(string privateKey)
    {
        UserProjection projection;

        try
        {
            projection = new UserProjection(_model.Get(privateKey));
        }
        catch (UserNotFoundException)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, projection);
    }
}
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20723447/126014

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Note**:
The original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19909129/467754) requires the *same* customization to be copied for each new ApiController.

**Generalized approach**

An alternative way is to automatically fill the `Request` property on all ApiControllers (thus saving you from cut, copy, and paste):

```
internal class ApiControllerCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customizations.Add(
            new FilteringSpecimenBuilder(
                new Postprocessor(
                    new MethodInvoker(
                        new ModestConstructorQuery()),
                    new ApiControllerFiller()),
                new ApiControllerSpecification()));
    }

    private class ApiControllerFiller : ISpecimenCommand
    {
        public void Execute(object specimen, ISpecimenContext context)
        {
            if (specimen == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("specimen");
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

            var target = specimen as ApiController;
            if (target == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    "The specimen must be an instance of ApiController.", 
                    "specimen");

            target.Request =
                (HttpRequestMessage)context.Resolve(
                    typeof(HttpRequestMessage));
        }
    }

    private class ApiControllerSpecification : IRequestSpecification
    {
        public bool IsSatisfiedBy(object request)
        {
            var requestType = request as Type;
            if (requestType == null)
                return false;
            return typeof(ApiController).IsAssignableFrom(requestType);
        }
    }
}
```

The value of type `HttpRequestMessage`, for the `Request` property, is built using the following customization:

```
internal class HttpRequestMessageCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<HttpRequestMessage>(c => c
            .Without(x => x.Content)
            .Do(x => x.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] =
                new HttpConfiguration()));
    }
}
```

**Packing everything into a composite Customization**

Create a Customization composite as below - note that [the order of AutoFixture Customizations matter](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/07/31/TheorderofAutoFixtureCustomizationsmatter/):

```
internal class ApiControllerConventions : CompositeCustomization
{
    internal ApiControllerConventions()
        : base(
            new HttpRequestMessageCustomization(),
            new ApiControllerCustomization(),
            new AutoMoqCustomization())
    {
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: this blog post might also help shed some light on the solution http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/08/how-to-automatically-populate-properties-with-automoq/

Answer (score 9):

<del>**Note**:</del>
<del>Assuming that the `UserController` class takes an `IUserModel` through its constructor.</del>

<del>As it looks like, the default constructor of `ApiController` performs some work (probably more than simple assignments).</del>

<del>If the `UserController` class takes an `IUserModel` through its constructor, [you can pick *that* constructor (the *greediest*) instead](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/19/ConstructorstrategiesforAutoFixture/).</del>

**Update**:

Replace the `HttpRequestMessageCustomization` customization with:

```
internal class ApiControllerCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<HttpRequestMessage>(c => c
            .Without(x => x.Content)
            .Do(x => x.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] =
                new HttpConfiguration()));

        fixture.Customize<UsersController>(c => c
            .OmitAutoProperties()
            .With(x => x.Request, fixture.Create<HttpRequestMessage>()));
    }
}
```

And the original test will execute fine.

Comment: Thanks for quick replay Nikos. I've added your suggested customization, but I still get the same exception thrown when I try to execute the test.

Comment: Did you replace the `HttpRequestMessageCustomization` with the proposed `ApiControllerCustomization`? If yes (and you are still having the same exception) how does the `UsersController` class looks like?

Comment: I've tried to add it along side `HttpRequestMessageCustomization` first. Then I've tried to replace it with `ApiControllerCustomization`. I had the same exception in both cases.

Comment: Does the suggestion Customization target classes that *derive* from `ApiController`?

Comment: @MarkSeemann it does. I've added `UsersController` code to examples list.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Correct.. I [updated the proposed customization](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19909129/revisions).

Comment: @user2910739 I updated the answer to also customize the `Request` property. Hope that helps...

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis it worked! Could you briefly explain how you came up with the solution?

Comment: @user2910739 Actually the solution came up after a few [small iterations](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19909129/revisions) :) AFAICT, all we need is to skip all properties except the `Content` which is actually filled using your code from the initial `HttpRequestMessageCustomization` class.

Comment: The example in this answer is pretty easy make generic by actually making it a generic class that takes the controller type. I went that route rather than the more verbose solution from the other answer. Thanks!

Comment: If you still want AutoMocking, you can add this line within this `Customize` method: `fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());`

Answer (score 2):

***Based on Nikos' answer:***

This is a more generic way of using this customization where the controller type can be supplied and the `Customization` can be used for any controller

```
internal class WebApiCustomization<TControllerType> : ICustomization
    where TControllerType : ApiController
    {
        public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
        {
            fixture.Customize<HttpRequestMessage>(c => c
                .Without(x => x.Content)
                .Do(x => x.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] =
                    new HttpConfiguration()));

            fixture.Customize<TControllerType>(c => c
                .OmitAutoProperties()
                .With(x => x.Request, fixture.Create<HttpRequestMessage>()));
}
}
```

Then use as follows:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(
    new WebApiCustomization<UsersController>());
var sut = fixture.Create<UsersController>();
```