# ArgumentNullException in a unit test for AutoFixture AutoDataAttribute

Tags: c#, moq, xunit.net, autofixture

I was writing a unit test for `ApiControllerConventions` from a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19954215/465056) and I wrote a `AutoMoqApiControllerDataAttribute` to integrate this `ICustomization` in xUnit.net.

```
public class AutoMoqApiControllerDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqApiControllerDataAttribute() : this(new Fixture())
    {
    }

    public AutoMoqApiControllerDataAttribute(IFixture fixture) : base(
        fixture.Customize(new ApiControllerConventions()))
    {
    }
}
```

I tried writing a unit test for this attribute like this:

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqDataAttribute() : this(new Fixture())
    {
    }

    public AutoMoqDataAttribute(IFixture fixture) : 
        base(fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization()))
    {
    }
}

[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void AutoMoqApiControllerDataAttribute_ContainsCorrectCustomization(
    Mock<IFixture> mockFixture)
{
    // Arrange
    mockFixture.Setup(f => f.Customize(It.IsAny<ApiControllerConventions>())).Verifiable();

    // Act
    var sut = new AutoMoqApiControllerDataAttribute(mockFixture.Object);

    // Assert
    mockFixture.Verify(f => f.Customize(It.IsAny<ApiControllerConventions>()), Times.Once);
}
```

This fails with an exception from `AutoDataAttribute`:

> System.ArgumentNullException
>   Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: fixture
>     at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Xunit2.AutoDataAttribute..ctor(IFixture fixture)

I thought this is related to my usage of the `AutoMoqDataAttribute` so I reverted to a vanilla `Fact`, same exception still:

```
[Fact]
public void AutoMoqApiControllerDataAttribute_ContainsCorrectCustomization()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockFixture = new Mock<IFixture>();
    mockFixture.Setup(f => f.Customize(It.IsAny<ApiControllerConventions>())).Verifiable();

    // Act
    var sut = new AutoMoqApiControllerDataAttribute(mockFixture.Object);

    // Assert
    mockFixture.Verify(f => f.Customize(It.IsAny<ApiControllerConventions>()), Times.Once);
}
```

Why am I getting the exception? I obviously have the `IFixture` mocked and it is definitely not null.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please share `AutoMoqApiControllerDataAttribute`.

Comment: It's at the top of my question :)

Comment: So it is. My mistake, sorry about that. I can now reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get an exception, it's always a good idea to look at the call stack. The exception isn't thrown in `AutoMoqApiControllerDataAttribute`, but in `AutoDataAttribute`:

```
System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: fixture
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Xunit2.AutoDataAttribute..ctor(IFixture fixture)
    AutoMoqApiControllerDataAttribute.cs(12,0): at _44380395.AutoMoqApiControllerDataAttribute..ctor(IFixture fixture)
    Tests.cs(22,0): at _44380395.Tests.AutoMoqApiControllerDataAttribute_ContainsCorrectCustomization()
```

While `fixture` isn't `null` when it's passed to `AutoMoqApiControllerDataAttribute`, it *is* `null` when passed to `base(IFixture)`.

Why?

Consider the call to `base`:

```
base(fixture.Customize(new ApiControllerConventions()))
```

Which value is being passed to `base`?

Not `fixture`, but the *return value* from invoking `fixture.Customize`.

The test doesn't set up a return value for this method call, so Moq defaults to the default value for the type. Since `IFixture` is a reference type, that means `null`, and that `null` value is then passed to `base`.

You can easily address the problem by configuring `mockFixture` with a return value in the test:

```
[Fact]
public void AutoMoqApiControllerDataAttribute_ContainsCorrectCustomization()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockFixture = new Mock<IFixture>();
    mockFixture
        .Setup(f => f.Customize(It.IsAny<ApiControllerConventions>()))
        .Returns(mockFixture.Object)
        .Verifiable();

    // Act
    var sut = new AutoMoqApiControllerDataAttribute(mockFixture.Object);

    // Assert
    mockFixture.Verify(
        f => f.Customize(It.IsAny<ApiControllerConventions>()),
        Times.Once());
}
```

Now the test passes in my repro.

This isn't a problem specific to AutoFixture. You could reproduce it with any [Fluent Interface](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html).

Comment: That's it! I couldn't believe I missed that! Thanks!